# Constructing a real valued function on a compact hausdorff space that does not vanish where two other functions don't vanish

Tags: general-topology

Setting:  $X$ compact hausdorff,  $f,g$ continuous real valued functions on $X$,  $x\in X$  such that $f(x)\ne 0,g(x)\ne 0$.   I need to find a continuous function $h$ that whenever $h(y)\ne 0$,  both $f\ne 0$  and $g\ne 0$...ie h not vanishing implies both f and g both don't vanish.

I tried obvious algebra tricks like $f^2 +g^2,(f-g)^2$, etc.  Didn't seem to work.  Then I thought about using continuity,  so we have for our point $x$, open neighborhoods $V,W$  where $f,g$ do not vanish, respectively, and looking at the neighborhood $V\cap W$.  Is it possible to make a function that doesn't vanish on $V\cap W$ but does outside?  Something like Urysohnn's lemma?

Comment: Equivalently, you want $h$ to have the property that if $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$, then $h(x)=0$. Why not take $h=fg$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Wow, I'm off my game tonight.  Thanks, if you want to change that to an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: My thoughts exactly. But the way the question is formulated even $h\equiv0$ would be acceptable.

Comment: @Alan: You’re welcome; done!

Comment: @Justpassingby That wouldn't do because there does exist a point x where both don't vanish, alas.

Comment: @Alan: there exists a point where $f$ and $g$ don't vanish. That does not contradict the fact that $h$ vanishes everywhere. The statement 'if $h(y)$ is nonzero then so are $f(y)$ and $g(y)$' remains logically true when the 'if' part is never satisfied.

Comment: @Justpassingby My apologies, the question was ill posed.  I needed BOTH conditions,  that statement and that h does not vanish on the one starting point that we knew f and g didn't vanish on

Comment: @Alan OK understood. While it should be clear that I greatly prefer Brian's answer, a compact Hausdorff space is normal so by Urysohn's lemma you can construct continuous functions $h$ that are 1 at $x$ and 0 outside an arbitrarily small neighbourhood of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalently, you want $h$ to have the property that if $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$, then $h(x)=0$. Why not take $h=fg$?